# React - Cannot read property 'state' of undefined

Tags: reactjs

I keep getting this error despite using a fat Arrow function the bind the context of this when using setState. Can anyone please help?

```
export default class App extends Component {

constructor(props) {
    super(props);
    this.state = {
        query: '',
        items: [],
        repos: []
    };
}

search(term) {
    this.setState({
        query: term
    });
    const clientId = '12489b7d9ed4251ebbca';
    const secret = 'ff53ac9a93aaa9e7cddc0c009d6f068302866ff2';

    function fetchUser() {
        return axios.get(`https://api.github.com/users/${this.state.query}/repos?client_id=${clientId}client_secret=${secret}`);
    }

    function fetchRepos() {
        return axios.get(`https://api.github.com/users/${this.state.query}?client_id=${clientId}client_secret=${secret}`);
    }

    axios.all([fetchUser(), fetchRepos()])
        .then(axios.spread((items, repos) => {
            this.setState({
                items: items.data,
                repos: repos.data

            });
            console.log(state);
        }));

}
```

Comment: Are you able to see the Line of code, where the error is happening?

Comment: It was failing at fetchUser. I just add this variable.

const query = this.state.query;

Thanks fixed it!

Comment: Added to my answer, that you should use arrow functions because they will reuse the parent `this`

Answer (score 3):

From the error message it seems clear that `this` is undefined. This is probably because you are using it in `search()` and `search()` isn't bound to the component, making `this` completely meaningless. To fix this try adding this line at the end of your constructor function:

```
        this.search = this.search.bind(this);
```

Now you should be able to use `this` in your search function.

Answer (score 0):

`setState` is not synchronous. If you want to use the value of the state after setting it, you have to provide a callback inside setState after the object.

This is how I would do it:

```
onSearch(term) {
  this.setState({ query: term }, () => {
    console.log(this.state.query);
    this.search();
  });
}

search() {
  // now you can be sure, that this.state.query is set and use it.. 

  // Use arrow functions, as they will reuse the parent scope.
  const fetchUser = () => {

  }
}
```

Comment: I would rather pass the term to the search function as a parameter instead of waiting for a callback.

Comment: Probably, if don't need the term in the UI you can forget about it of course. At the other side, sometimes you would like to perform the query again with the same set of params (from the state) like in the OP, in this case it's better to have a single method search, which will rely on the state. When changing the query params, we first should update the state and then perform the search. Btw, I just found it useful to demonstrate the setState + callback

Comment: I am thinking about some more complex search forms with tags / categories and so on. In React every change would have another event handler like `onTags`, `onCategories`, `onSearchTerm`. So you can still call a single `search` method after your state has updated.

Answer (score 0):

If an error from `fetchUser` i think you have correct `this` in `search` function. So you need to bind `fetchUser` and `fetchRepos`:

```
const fetchUser = () => {
        return axios.get(`https://api.github.com/users/${this.state.query}/repos?client_id=${clientId}client_secret=${secret}`);
    }
```

Or

```
const fetchUser = function(){
        return axios.get(`https://api.github.com/users/${this.state.query}/repos?client_id=${clientId}client_secret=${secret}`);
    }.bind(this);
```

And the same for `fetchRepos`.

Comment: @Dennis, Is this answer helped?